# finding the integral of: $1/((1+x^2)^n)$

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the integral of  $1/((1+x^2)^n)$?

I have tried adding and substracting $x^2$ from the numerator

$$ \int \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}\:dx = \int \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}\,dx − \int \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\,dx $$

but can't see how to proceed from here.

Comment: Also [Reduction formula for$\int\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$ by  $x=\tan u$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/651713)

Comment: Sketch: Let $I_n$ be our integral. We obtain a reduction formula, by finding $I_{n-1}$ using integration by parts, $du=dx$ and $v=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}$. Your trick will come up.

Comment: Take x = tan y. The problem is reduced to finding the integral of cos y.

Comment: dx = sec^2(y) dy = (1+ tan^2(y)) dy