# Reduction formula

Tags: integration

**Let**$\ I_n = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n} dx$. **Prove that for every positive integer n,** 
$$\ 2nI_{n+1} = 2^{-n}+(2n-1)I_n$$

**Attempt**

$$\ I_{n+1} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}} dx$$
$$\ I_{n+1} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}} dx-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}} dx$$
$$\ I_{n+1} = I_n-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}} dx$$
$$\ I_{n+1} = I_n-[\frac{-2^{-n}}{2n}+\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n}} dx]$$
$$\ 2nI_{n+1} = 2nI_n+2^{-n}-2I_n $$
$$\ 2nI_{n+1} = (2n-2)I_n+2^{-n} $$

Can somebody please tell me the mistake I am doing?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651713/reduction-formula-for-int-fracdx1x2n-by-x-tan-u

Comment: I am aware of other methods but I want to know what mistake I am making over here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Can somebody please tell me the mistake I am doing?*

I see a mistake when you integrate by parts, you have forgotten the factor $\dfrac12$ in front of the second integral, one rather has, for $n\ge1$,
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}} dx=\left[x\cdot-\frac{1}{2n(1+x^2)^{n}}\right]_{0}^{1}+\frac1{2n}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n} dx.
$$ from which
$$
I_n-I_{n+1}=-\frac{2^{-n}}{2n}+\frac1{2n}I_n
$$ or

> $$\ 2nI_{n+1} = 2^{-n}+(2n-1)I_n$$

as announced.

Comment: How is there a factor of 1/2 present in thee second integral. The coefficient due to integrated term is 1/2n and coefficient due to differentiated term is 2. Thus both 2's cancel out.

Comment: Wait are we first going to divide x^2 by x( from the integrated part) or will we first differentiate x^2 and then divide the X?

Comment: We use $\int u dv=uv-\int v du$ with $u=\frac x2$ and $dv=\frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}$ giving $du=\frac12$ and $v=-\frac{1}{n(1+x^2)^{n}}$. Tell me if it is Ok.

Comment: Can you tell me what will be v and du if  $\ dv = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}$ and $\ u = x^2 $?

Comment: @FaiqRaees If we knew an antiderivative of $dv = \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}$ we would directly use it to find out what $I_n$ is... But this is not the case, that's why we rather take $dv = \frac{2x}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}$ which is way easier to integrate...

Comment: Oh okay I was mistaken by considering that $\ \int f(x)^n =\frac{f(x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)*\frac{d}{dx}f(x)} $