# How to solve $\int x^2\sqrt{x^2 + 4}dx$

Tags: integration

How to solve $\int x^2\sqrt{x^2 + 4}dx$?

If I will make integration by parts, I will get $\int \frac{x^4}{x^2 + 4}$, and I do not know what do with this integral.

Comment: $$x^4=(x^2-2)(x^2+2)+4$$

Comment: Substitute $x=2\sinh u$

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651713/reduction-formula-for-int-fracdx1x2n-by-x-tan-u as $$x^2=(x^2+4)-4$$

Comment: @Eugene Apart from the fact that others have provided solutions, you do know how to perform long division $x^4$ by $x^2+4$?

Comment: You don't get the second integral from doing by parts on the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x=2\sinh u$, so you get
$$
I=16\int\sinh^2u\cosh^2u\,du=
4\int\sinh^22u\,du=4\int\frac{\cosh4u-1}{2}\,du
$$

Answer (score 0):

Sub $x= 2\tan\theta, dx=2\sec^2\theta d\theta$

$\int x^2\sqrt{x^2 + 4}dx$

$=\int 4\tan^2\theta \sqrt{4\tan^2\theta+4}(2\sec^2\theta) d\theta$

$=\int (4\sec^2\theta-4) (2\sec^3\theta) d\theta$

$=8\int \sec^5\theta-\sec^3\theta  d\theta$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = 2 \tan u$ then $dx = 2 \sec^2u~ du$. Now substitute in the integral
\begin{align}
\int x^2 \sqrt{x^2+4} ~dx &= \int 4 \tan^2 u \sqrt{4 \tan^2u+4} ~2\sec^2u~du \\
&= 8 \int \tan^2 u \sqrt{4\sec^2u} ~\sec^2u~du \\
&= 16 \int \tan^2 u \sec u ~\sec^2u~du \\
&= 16 \int \tan^2 u \sec^3 u ~du \\
&= 16 \int (\sec^2u-1) \sec^3 u ~du \\
&= 16 \int \sec^5u - \sec^3 u ~du \\
& = 16 \left( \frac{1}{8} (3\ln(|\tan u+\sec u|)+\sec u(2\sec^2 u+3)\tan u) - \frac{1}{2}(\ln(|\tan u+\sec u|)+\sec u\tan u)\right) + C
\end{align}
Now, since $\tan u = \frac{x}{2}$, then $\sec u = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$. Therefore
\begin{align}
\int x^2 \sqrt{x^2+4} ~dx &= 16 \left( \frac{1}{8} (3\ln(|\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}|)+ \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2} (2(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2})^2 +3)\frac{x}{2}) - \frac{1}{2}(\ln(|\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}|)+ \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2} \frac{x}{2})\right)+C\\
& = 16 \left( \frac{1}{8} (3\ln(|\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}|)+ \frac{x\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2} (\frac{x^2+4}{4} +3) - \frac{1}{2}(\ln(|\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}|)+ \frac{x\sqrt{x^2+4}}{4})\right)+C
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

Write :

$$\frac{x^4}{x^2+4}=x^2-4+\frac{16}{x^2+4}$$

And now integrate both the sides.